# Copy data from DataGrid View to another B

Tags: vb.net

I want to copy data from DataGrid View to another, as follows
[image]

The second DataGrid View contains 8 columns, they are actually a duplicate of the first DataGrid, but in order for the data to be grouped next to some

[image]

What do I want to collect data from the first DataGrid View by the second so that the columns that start inside the first column with the letter A in the first DataGrid View, which bears the symbol B in the second part of the DataGrid View 2, have the same name as it

[image]

And it becomes the final shape with the knowledge that the columns of the letter A can be more or vice versa, but the request is the same as collecting data next to some, even if some fields appear empty when the fields between A, B are not equal.
[image]

```
    For ii = 0 To DATAG_CLIENT.Rows.Count - 1

        If DATAG_CLIENT.Rows(ii).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Contains("A") Then
            PRINTSHOW.DATGR_PRINT.Rows(ii).Cells(0).Value = DATAG_CLIENT.Rows(ii).Cells(2).Value
            PRINTSHOW.DATGR_PRINT.Rows(ii).Cells(1).Value = DATAG_CLIENT.Rows(ii).Cells(3).Value
            PRINTSHOW.DATGR_PRINT.Rows(ii).Cells(2).Value = DATAG_CLIENT.Rows(ii).Cells(4).Value
            PRINTSHOW.DATGR_PRINT.Rows(ii).Cells(3).Value = DATAG_CLIENT.Rows(ii).Cells(5).Value
        End If

        If DATAG_CLIENT.Rows(ii).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Contains("B") Then
            PRINTSHOW.DATGR_PRINT.Rows(ii).Cells(4).Value = DATAG_CLIENT.Rows(ii).Cells(2).Value
            PRINTSHOW.DATGR_PRINT.Rows(ii).Cells(5).Value = DATAG_CLIENT.Rows(ii).Cells(3).Value
            PRINTSHOW.DATGR_PRINT.Rows(ii).Cells(6).Value = DATAG_CLIENT.Rows(ii).Cells(4).Value
            PRINTSHOW.DATGR_PRINT.Rows(ii).Cells(7).Value = DATAG_CLIENT.Rows(ii).Cells(5).Value
        End If

    Next 'BAD RESULT
```

[image]

Comment: You haven't shown us any code so we can't tell you exactly what you're doing wrong but from the output it is obvious that you are adding one row in the second grid for every row in the first grid. That is obviously wrong. If all the "A" rows come first then you add a new row in the second grid for those and, for the "B" rows, you need to find an existing row that matches the name first and edit that, not add a new row.

Comment: Basically, this is what happens when people try to write code without knowing what it has to do, i.e. not just the end result but the steps to get there. Stop writing code, do the task manually and think about the steps you actually perform. Formalise those steps into an algorithm and then write code specifically to implement that algorithm. If it doesn't work, you should be able to show us the code AND the algorithm and explain exactly where and how the behaviour of the former differs from the latter. If you haven't done all that, it's really too soon to post here.

Comment: How did you fill the original DataGridView?

Comment: I think this would be somewhat easier if you used 2 different grids for the divided data, one for the A group and one for the B group. You could place them next to each other on the form.